# Step by step Google SSO (java)?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am lost in all my open browser tabs for Google single sign on :)

I already have an application which I would like to put on Google market place. And mandatory integration is Google SSO. I have built application on Struts2 with Spring.

So now I need some instructions how to make this integration. An example would be perfect. Or how to start, which technology to use, best approaches, anything similar...

Also, **do I have to** use Google App Engine for SSO integration or no? Honestly, I am confused :)

**EDIT**

I started here: [developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso](http://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso) Because I use Java, if you look at Getting started at the bottom, I wanted to use step2, but the link is dead. From there on I got stuck...

Links [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/open-source#sso) are also dead.

Comment: Why don't you show what you've tried so far and tell us where you got stuck? I've gotten SSO working with twitter and facebook so I'm pretty sure google should be as easy.

Comment: I also did it with Facebook and Dropbox, that was easy. But I can't even find where to start with Google. I just got confused. I started here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso Because I use Java, if you look at Getting started at the bottom, I wanted to use step2, but the link is dead. From there on I got stuck...

Comment: I agree looking at that documentation is pretty bad.

Comment: @Trick: i believe you are looking for this http://code.google.com/p/step2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made with Apache's HttpClient. This is my solution and works perfectly for me.

First point to authorization url:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&state=%2Fprofile&response_type=code&client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<YOUR_CALLBACK_URL>`

Then get parameters back from your `redirect_uri` and build request body for getting `access_token`:

```
    String code =  request.getParameter("code");
    String foros = "code="+code +
                "&client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>" +
                "&client_secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>" +
                "&redirect_uri="+getText("google.auth.redirect.uri") +
                "&grant_type=authorization_code";
```

Then with HttpClient make a POST and with simple JSON parser parse out the access token.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
    post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(foros, null, null));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    String accessToken = null;
    try {
        client.executeMethod(post);
        String resp = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(resp);
        JSONObject parsed = (JSONObject)obj;            
        accessToken = (String) parsed.get("access_token");
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Now you have the access token and you can now access **all** of the Google API. For example, getting all the users info:

```
    GetMethod getUserInfo = new GetMethod("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="+accessToken);

    String googleId = null;
    String email = null;
    String name = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    try {
        client.executeMethod(getUserInfo);
        String resp = getUserInfo.getResponseBodyAsString();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(resp);
        JSONObject parsed = (JSONObject)obj;
        googleId = (String) parsed.get("id");
        email = (String) parsed.get("email");
        name = (String) parsed.get("name");
        firstName = (String) parsed.get("given_name");
        lastName = (String) parsed.get("family_name");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

This data you can now save and use it for login to your application.

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the Java tutorial for the Google Apps Marketplace which explains how to perform Single Sign-On: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_java

The tutorial also includes a download link for a zip with the application source and all the required libraries, including step2: http://apps-marketplace-resources.googlecode.com/files/helloworld-java-2011050303.zip

Here are valid links for the broken ones in the docs:

- step2: http://code.google.com/p/step2/
- openid4java: http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/
- gdata-java-client: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/