# Issues in setting Authentication after successfull google SSO login in Spring Security and Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Google SSO in my Spring Boot Application. Used this thread for same.
[Step by step Google SSO (java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195225/step-by-step-google-sso-java)

1. I am using HttpClient to call first google endpoint to get the google sign in - where user can add google creadentials.
2. It gets redirected to the redirect_url configuration set, which in turn calls my Controller \login, where I get the code returned by google api, there I send another api call to get access_token
3. In my LoginController, I am able to get the user details, but I do not know how to manage adding it in Authentication and make it available for other controllers. I also want to use these User details for Audit purpose.

Below is my code for main classes

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SecurityFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        try {
            // How to check here if authentication already done.
            String redirectUrl = GoogleSSORestClient.getRedirectUrl();
            resp.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
  
@Controller
 
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    LoginService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams, ModelMap model){
        
        if(!allRequestParams.containsKey("access_token")) {
            String code =allRequestParams.get("code");
            String accessToken = GoogleSSORestClient.getAccessToken(code);
            User user = getUserInfo(accessToken);
            
            if (user != null) {
                //UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                  //      new Credentials(type, decodedToken, token, session), null);
                //authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                 
                if (user != null) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                            new Credentials(), null);
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return "success";
    }
      
private User getUserInfo(String accessToken) {
    User user = null;
     
    String urlToRead = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessToken;
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlToRead);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String id = null;
    
    String picture = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   // try {
         conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
         try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
             for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                 result.append(line);
             }
         }
        //JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        JSONObject parsed = (JSONObject)obj;
        id = (String) parsed.get("id");
         
        picture = (String) parsed.get("picture");
        
        user = new User();
        user.setId(googleId);
        user.setPicture(picture);
         
    }catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    
    return user;
}


}
```

I have added SecurityConfig, but not sure if I should go with Authentication Provider

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    SecurityProperties restSecProps;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
            Map<String, Object> errorObject = new HashMap<>();
            int errorCode = 401;
            errorObject.put("message", "Unauthorized access of protected resource, invalid credentials");
            errorObject.put("error", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            errorObject.put("code", errorCode);
            errorObject.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(errorCode);
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorObject));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(restSecProps.getAllowedOrigins());
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(restSecProps.getAllowedMethods());
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(restSecProps.getAllowedHeaders());
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(restSecProps.isAllowCredentials());
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(restSecProps.getExposedHeaders());
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(restSecProps.getAllowedPublicApis().toArray(new String[1])).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);*/
        
        /*String redirectUrl = GoogleSSOClient.getRedirectUrl();
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            
            .loginPage(redirectUrl) 
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login") 
            .permitAll(); */
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions will be of great help.
Thanks,